# What is wrong with this command block code?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to get whenever you hold an item (diamond sword) it will give you particles. I know how to do this but not when something has a custom name.

```
/scoreboard players set @a HoldSword 1 {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:diamond_sword"{display:{Name:"&4FadedSharp's Sword"}}
```

I don't know what is wrong with this code; can someone please help me?

Comment: What're you trying to do and what is it not doing?

Comment: @rivermont-WillB. Please do not use quotations for commands, as they are not quotations. Use code blocks instead (4 spaces, as it was before your edit).

Answer (score 1):

Data that you specify in `/give`, such as `{display:{Name:"&4FadedSharp's Sword"}}`, is put into the item's `tag` tag. You can test for it like this:

```
/scoreboard players set @a HoldSword 1 {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:diamond_sword",tag:{display:{Name:"&4FadedSharp's Sword"}}}}
```

Comment: it would say unbalanced brackets pls help

Comment: @FadedSharp The command he provided is syntactically correct and works. If you're changing the command, you need to provide the new command.

Answer (score 0):

you wrote the code for the name and forgot the "tag" before saying the name, the correct way of writing it is:

```
/scoreboard players set @a HoldSword 1 {SelectedItem:{id:minecraft:diamond_sword,tag:{display:{Name:"&4FadedSharp's Sword"}}}}
```

you must add a "tag" before the "{display:{Name:"SWORDS NAME"}"

Comment: it would say this: [21:14:39] The dataTag does not match for FadedSharp

Comment: yes, because you didn't hold the diamond sword called "&4FadedSharp's Sword" you must be holding it to be activated

Comment: @FadedSharp did it work for you